# Highcharts min y-axis value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to set a min y-axis value when the series values are the same?

For example:

http://jsfiddle.net/6hyfk/1/

I would like to see 0.00019 as y-axis value.

If i change it to:

```
series: [{

            data: [0.00019,0.00020,0.00019,0.00019]        
        }]
```

it looks a lot better.

Comment: Actually looks like a bug in highcharts.

Answer (score 3):

So the answer largely depends on your data. If for example, you know your values are all positive, setting a yAxis min helps your data display a bit better. You know your data better than I, so I'd look at the [yAxis settings](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis) and see what you can change to get a better result, but for example, this is a JSFiddle that sets a minimum value:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            tickLength: 20
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0  
        },
        series: [{

            data: [0.00019,0.00019,0.00019,0.00019]        
        }]
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gTG2z/

Comment: max could work as well, but I'm making the assumption that data is more frequently limited at a 0 minimum, whereas the maximum for the data values here could be .001, 1, or 100 so setting a maximum may be less useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually set the min and max on the X axis.

```
yAxis:{
    min: 0,
    max: .001
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6hyfk/2/

Answer (score 1):

If you know what range is in your series, you can set accordingly `minRange`, so Highcharts will render more ticks as expected. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/6hyfk/3/ Good thing about `minRange` is that it will work also for another values like that: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/6hyfk/5/

Answer (score 0):

Probably,you don't need to hardcode min,max values.Do calculation for min and max and set to y Axis as shown below,

```
$(function () {
    yMin = Math.min.apply(Math,data); // Find Min
    yMax = Math.max.apply(Math,data); //Find Max
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: yMin,
            max: yMax 
        },
        series: [{

            data: data //Array of values        
        }]
    });
});
```